# Putting loop inside a Select Case generates error

Tags: excel, vba

I have put a `do`/`while` statement inside a `SELECT CASE`/`END SELECT` and it generates the error

> Case without Select Case.

```
Select Case myVariable
    Case 0
        Do
        While ...
    Case 1
    ...
End Select
```

Comment: Try Do … Loop While ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how `Do While` loops work. Is has nothing to do with your `Select Case`

try it like this:

```
Sub test()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer

  y = 0

  Select Case y
    Case 0
      Do While x < 10
        x = x + 1
      Loop
      MsgBox x
    Case 1
      MsgBox "end"
  End Select

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub test()
  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer

  y = 0

  Select Case y
    Case 0
      Do 
        x = x + 1
      Loop While x < 10
      MsgBox x
    Case 1
      MsgBox "end"
  End Select

End Sub
```

[Do Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doloop-statement)

Comment: The OP seems to want the condition at the end (which makes a difference). So, `Do: x = x + 1: Loop While x < 10`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
Dim myvariable As Integer
myvariable = 0

Select Case myvariable
   Case Is = 0
        i = 0
         Do
              MsgBox i
              i = i + 1
         Loop While (i < 10)
  Case Else
      MsgBox "Else"
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

another alternative use

```
Select Case myVariable
    Case 0
        Dim Counter
        Counter = 0 ' Initialize variable.
        While Counter < 20 ' Test value of Counter.
             Counter = Counter + 1 ' Increment Counter.
        Wend ' End While loop when Counter > 19.
        Debug.Print Counter ' Prints 20 in the Immediate window.
    Case 1
    ...
End Select
```